# JPA / Hibernate removing "child" entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two entity classes *A* and *B* that exist in a bidirectional one-to-many relationship respectively.

**A.java:**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "aId",
           fetch=FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval=true)
private Set<B> bCollection = new LinkedHashSet<B>();
```

**B.java**

```
  @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable=false)
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)   
  private A aId;
```

In a simple console application I obtain a specific *A* row from the database and try to delete one of its detail *B* rows (at random) but **JPA/Hibernate** not only does remove the row - it doesn't even issue any **DELETE** statements towards the database. The only way to remove the *B* row is by removing the corresponding entity from the collection (**LinkedHashSet**) of **A.java**. So, while I have a workaround, I would like to understand why the below code fails, and fails quietly too!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testjpa");
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction entityTransaction = em.getTransaction();
    entityTransaction.begin();
    A a = em.find(A.class, 1);
    B b = getARandomChildOfA(a);
    em.remove(em.merge(b));     // simple em.remove(b) doesn't work either
    entityTransaction.commit();
    em.close();
    entityManagerFactory.close();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JPA doesn't manage relations for you, so while you have called remove on b, a still has a reference to it.  Since the reference has a cascade persist/merge set on it, it causes b to be resurrected in the context, undoing the remove.

You must maintain references to keep your model in sync with what you want in the database.  It is good practice to null out references to objects you are removing and set back pointers unless you are sure you can deal with potential inconsistencies such as this.

Comment: Some clarification if I may: (1) in which call does resurrection occur and is there any way to see it ? (for testing) (2) Can't I always use the EntityManager::remove method to remove "top-level" objects (i.e. objects that don't appear in some other object's collection) and their entire graph ? (3) I am puzzled a bit by the "null out references to objects you are removing and set back pointers" wording. What I did was to remove B from A's collection and set B::aId to null. Is that what you refer to? Nullifying B:aId seems superfluous though. Is this dictated by the JPA specification?

Comment: Resurrection is likely occurring on the comit, as that is when changes should be picked up.  2) not sure what you mean.  You can remove any entity, but you have to manage any references to it as you would any java object.  3)I meant null out references to deleted objects.  Prune them from the tree as well as remove them

Comment: @Chris Saved my day! thanks chris. Had exactly same situation you described in second paragraph. Cascade.remove FTW :-)