# Deleting an object in a SpringBoot 2.0.5.RELEASE app using Spring Data JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a basic SpringBoot 2.0.5.RELEASE app. Using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I have this class:

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true, 
                fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "user")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Wallet> wallets = new ArrayList<Wallet>();

..
}
```

and this one:

```
public class Wallet implements Serializable {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    @NotNull
    private Invoice invoice;



    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "wallet", 
               cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
               orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Purchase> purchases = new HashSet<>();


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id" , nullable=false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;

..
}
```

and this other one:

```
public class Purchase implements Serializable {

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
            @JoinColumn(name = "wallet_id")
            @JsonIgnore
            Wallet wallet;

        ...

    }
```

But I delete a wallet form the controller that have an invoice and purchases and belong to a user the wallet is not deleted from the DB

```
walletService.delete(walletService.findById(id).get());
```

this is the service method:

```
@Transactional
    public void delete(Wallet wallet) {
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("deleting Wallet [ " + wallet + " ]");
        }


        wallet
            .getPurchases()
            .parallelStream()
            .forEach(p -> purchaseService.delete(p));

        walletRepository.delete(wallet);

    }
```

and

```
 @Transactional
     public void delete (Purchase purchase ) {
         purchaseRepository.delete (purchase);
     }
```

in the properties file:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

and the last query I see in the console is this one:

```
select
    purchases0_.wallet_id as wallet_i8_13_0_,
    purchases0_.id as id1_13_0_,
    purchases0_.id as id1_13_1_,
    purchases0_.amount as amount2_13_1_,
    purchases0_.wallet_id as wallet_i8_13_1_ 
from
    t_purchase purchases0_ 
where
    purchases0_.wallet_id=?
```

and no delete and no Exceptions !!! !

Comment: 1) do you get any exceptions? 2) can you see the delete SQL statements?

Comment: Try using cascading and why you are doing walletService.delete(walletService.findById(id).get());, only walletService.findById(id) will get you and object so i dont think you need to do get(),

Comment: which jpa interface the wallet repository is extending from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in the controller:

```
    user.getWallets().remove(wallet);
    walletService.delete(wallet);       
    userService.save(user);
```

Comment: userService.save(user);
is at best redudant since the @transactional take care of persisting changes made to managed entities (e.g. user)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 Cases here

1. You have added `mappedBy` in `Wallet` Class so `Purchase` is owner entity and you need to delete from `Purchases`

   try changing delete Wallet method like this

   ```
   @Transactional
   public void delete(Wallet wallet) {
       if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
           LOG.debug("deleting Wallet [ " + wallet + " ]");
       }

       wallet.getPurchases().removeAll();
   walletRepository.delete(wallet);

   }
   ```
2. Ideally you have configured `CascadeType.ALL` in `Wallet` so doing

   walletRepository.delete(wallet);

   should remove `Set<Purchase>`  too.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be possible solution: Hibernate configuration -> `orphanRemoval = true` will delete wallets only in case User entity is deleted?

Comment: I mean User is owner entity?

Answer (score 0):

## Problem Description

> The problem raise when you are trying to remove each children by
>   itself while the parent (i.e. parent) still has a reference to it and
>   since the reference has a cascade All   set on it (including persist
>   and merge), it causes child (i.e. purchase) to be revived in the
>   context by undoing the remove.

- Keep in mind that references mirror what should be happen in database, so you should null out references to objects you are removing otherwise you won't achieve the desire state you're expecting

source : [JPA / Hibernate removing "child" entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145045/jpa-hibernate-removing-child-entities)

---

## Solution

Get rid of removing children by making a stream on parent and change wallet class to have **cascade remove** type on *purchases* relationship :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "wallet", 
           cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE,  // <--- here should be changed
           orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Purchase> purchases = new HashSet<>();
```

Then you just need to call `walletRepository.delete(wallet);` to delete parent and children altogether.